# Anything equivalent for @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW) in seam?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, seam, transactional

I need to have a `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)` and in a non EJB enviroment, how can we get the same using `@Transactional` in Seam?

Is any of the values the same as REQUIRES_NEW?

```
REQUIRED,
MANDATORY, 
SUPPORTS,
NEVER
```

Or is there maybe some other annotation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, you *would* use  [@Transactional](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.1.CR3/reference/en-US/html/annotations.html#d0e26179) for non EJB environments, which comes with the 4 types you listed.

I vaguely remember that I read something about a new type "REQUIRES_NEW" in the developer mailing-list, which I found [here:](http://old.nabble.com/Implementing-REQUIRES_NEW-for-seam-transaction-management-td25219048.html)

Only problem is that it seems as if the patch never made it into trunk, I have 2.2.1.CR1 on my machine and TransactionPropagationType reads like this:

```
    public enum TransactionPropagationType
{
   REQUIRED,
   MANDATORY, 
   SUPPORTS,
   NEVER;
...
   }
```

Comment: Nice find. Thanks. So basically this means it is sort of "forgotten"